# Dynamic json array make same key as one array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a `json` array as follows , this data is from an excel sheet and converted it to `json` format.

```
[{
  'booktitle': 'Leading',
  'bookid': '56353',
  'bookauthor': 'Sir Alex Ferguson'
}, {
  'booktitle': 'How Google Works',
  'bookid': '73638',
  'bookauthor': 'Eric Smith'
}, {
  'booktitle': 'The Merchant of Venice',
  'bookid': '37364',
  'bookauthor': 'William Shakespeare'
}]
```

I would like to get value with same key in one array. This key value pair will be dynamic so want a solution in general.

Comment: What is the key here can you explain little more clearly

Comment: What have you tried? Post your attempt.

Comment: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: How to group array of objects by key :this  example is similar, but my key value pair will be dynamic, in this case booktitle,bookid,bookauthor are the keys but  in others cases it will be different and the count will also  be different so how get values if we don't know the key in json array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Array map Object keys like this,

```js
let arr = [{
    "booktitle": "Leading",
    "bookid": "56353",
    "bookauthor": "Sir Alex Ferguson"
}, {
    "booktitle": "How Google Works",
    "bookid": "73638",
    "bookauthor": "Eric Smith"
}, {
    "booktitle": "The Merchant of Venice",
    "bookid": "37364",
    "bookauthor": "William Shakespeare"
}];

let ans=Object.keys(arr[0]).map((key) => {
    let o={};
    o[key]=arr.map((x) => x[key]);
    return o;
});

console.log(ans);
```

Comment: This code helped. Just needed to add let data = JSON.parse(arr) as my json array needed formatting. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this. If you want to add anything else, please let me know.
Check the code snippet.

```js
const obj = [{
  'booktitle': 'Leading',
  'bookid': '56353',
  'bookauthor': 'Sir Alex Ferguson'
}, {
  'booktitle': 'How Google Works',
  'bookid': '73638',
  'bookauthor': 'Eric Smith'
}, {
  'booktitle': 'The Merchant of Venice',
  'bookid': '37364',
  'bookauthor': 'William Shakespeare'
}];

const res = obj.reduce((a, b) => {
  for(let i in b) {
    if(!a[i]) {
      a[i] = [];
    }
    a[i].push(b[i]);
  }
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let bookInfo = [{
  'booktitle': 'Leading',
  'bookid': '56353',
  'bookauthor': 'Sir Alex Ferguson'
}, {
  'booktitle': 'How Google Works',
  'bookid': '73638',
  'bookauthor': 'Eric Smith'
}, {
 'booktitle': 'The Merchant of Venice',
 'bookid': '37364',
 'bookauthor': 'William Shakespeare'
}]

  var bookTitle = [];
  var bookId   = [];
  var bookAuthor = [];

 bookInfo.filter(function(data){
      if(data.booktitle){
          bookTitle.push(data.booktitle);
       }

       if(data.bookid){
          bookId.push(data.bookid);
       }


       if(data.bookauthor){
          bookAuthor.push(data.bookauthor);
       }

 })
```